# Source object access from ColumnSet

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I try to split a sub-object in my recordset when importing data with initCB properties of a Column in ColumnSet.

But when I use two different init functions for two different destination names but one source I get same result.

```js
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
  'id',
  { name: 'source_id', prop: 'source', init: function(obj) { return obj.value.id; } },
  { name: 'source_name', prop: 'source', init: function(obj) { return obj.value.name; } },
], { table: 'test_table' });

const data = [
  { id: 1, source: { id: 1, name: 'source1' } },
  { id: 2, source: { id: 1, name: 'source1' } },
  { id: 3, source: { id: 2, name: 'source2' } },
];

const insert = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs);
```

The result is:

```sql
INSERT INTO "test_table"("id","source_id","source_name") VALUES
  (1,'source1','source1'),
  (2,'source1','source1'),
  (3,'source2','source2')
```

instead of expected:

```sql
INSERT INTO "test_table"("id","source_id","source_name") VALUES
  (1,1,'source1'),
  (2,1,'source1'),
  (3,2,'source2')
```

It seems like second invocation of callback function for THE SAME source field overriding result of previous invocation of ANOTHER callback function on THIS source field.

How I can avoid this?
Or there is another way of splitting a sub-object during import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `prop` doesn't quite work that way. It is there to remap the `value` to a different property name, but it does not supply the direct object reference.

Instead, use property `source` of the [column descriptor](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.initCB), to reference the source object. Ironically, you called the property in your data `source` as well, which means you will have to use `source` twice in your reference:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'id',
    {name: 'source_id', init: c => c.source.source.id},
    {name: 'source_name', init: c => c.source.source.name}
], {table: 'test_table'});
```

The first `source` is what `pg-promise` API supports, while the second is your data column name :)

Also, as per [documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.initCB), the API sets `source` and `this` to the same, so if you prefer the ES5 function syntax (looks cleaner for your example), then you can do this instead:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'id',
    { name: 'source_id', init: function() {return this.source.id;}},
    { name: 'source_name', init: function() {return this.source.name;}},
], { table: 'test_table' });
```

Above we have `this` point at the source data object.